# Can all kinds of wights be killed by weapons forged with dragon fire?

Tags: game-of-thrones, dragons

In some questions (see [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35871/weapons-that-can-kill-white-walkers), for instance) it is reported that, according to what was stated in the books and proved in the TV show, wights and white walkers can be killed using a weapon that was forged with dragon fire:

- obsidian
- fire itself (for wights)
- Valyrian steel

Fire and obsidian was proven effective against wights in the last episode of season 7, where

> Jon Snow confirmed that the wight brought to Cersei could be killed "by fire" or "with dragonglass"

However, due to the events happening in Season 7,

> Viserion was killed and brought back by the Night King.

Does dragonglass or fire work in this situation too? I ask this because

> Viserion (a wight) is actually a dragon, it can produce fire itself (probably, as discussed in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/168185/was-it-ice-or-fire)), and it is said that obsidian is either created by dragons or by fire in the Earth ([source](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Dragonglass))

Comment: A little bit of confusion. We don't see any WW killed by fire, and Viserion is a wight and not a WW. Finally, the fire produced by Viserion is not regular fire

Comment: Updated with better details. WW are not killed by fire, but wights are. Viserion is a wight. There is a doubt on the fact that it produces fire or not.

Comment: "(possibly) Valyrian steel (not proven)" we see Jon killing one with his Valyrian sword, how "not proven"?

Comment: That is right, I was citing the mentioned question, but I think that is not precise. I'll update the question.

Comment: What do you mean by `all types`? There are only 2 types of them till now. One are the White Walkers who are leading the dead, and the other is the  Night King.

Comment: @Dawny33: I believe Eleanore is asking whether *dragon wights* can be killed using dragon-forged weapons (obsidian and/or Valyrian steel), but has considerately left that out of the title to avoid spoilers. Using “White Walkers” in the title was confusing, but wights/white walkers is confusing terminology. [Blame *Lost*.](http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php?/topic/103088-the-white-walkers-why-name-change/)

Comment: @Kepotx: “the fire produced by Viserion is not regular fire ” *[citation needed]*

Comment: @PaulD.Waite exactly, I could not put spoilers in the title, the reference is exactly to the dragon :) Never safe enough with spoilers!

Comment: @Federico: we see Jon Snow killing a *White Walker* with his Valyrian steel sword. I’m not sure we see him killing (perhaps “de-animating” is a better term) a wight with Valyrian steel in the same way that the obsidian dagger shut down the Kings Landing demo wight.

Comment: @all in the last episode Jon Snow says that [SPOILER] the wight they bring to the Dragon Pit can be killed with either fire or dragonglass. Not sure if Valyrian steel applies to wight too.

Comment: I believe it may be unclear as to whether obsidian is created by dragonfire or not. It seems from what I have read to actually be volcanic glass with magical properties and is simply called dragonglass because of its magical properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## We Don't Know

We can speculate that most wights can be killed by "dragonfire weapons" from what we've seen:

- Human: Killed by Valyrian Steel, Dragonglass and fire.
- Bear: Killed by Dragonglass, not clear if the fire would have killed it eventually.
- Giant: No information yet.

From the information given it would appear that all wights can be killed by these weapons but we simply don't have enough to go on.

However, dragon fire is a common theme with these weapons and a dragon is a magical creature unlike the other wights we see. Therefore, we can't really compare "normal" wights to a dragon wight as the semantics of them are more than likely quite different. I'm sure we'll get the true answer in Season 8.

To update on this as Viserion actually appears to be a "White Flyer" according to the official script so the situation regarding him is even more complicated.

> *A massive chunk of the Wall breaks free ahead of Tormund. The ice dragon glides away, and we get our first clear look at him, and at the Night King on his back. He's done the same thing to Viserion that he did to Craster's sons. Only those were babies, and this is a dragon.*
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 7 Episode 7, "The Dragon and the Wolf"</sub>

Comment: “I'm sure we'll get the true answer in Season 8.” Assuming anyone can get near enough to the dragonwight to try it. For all we know, this could be the first dragonwight that has ever existed.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I agree so I suppose it depends on the ending

Comment: I think only Drogon and Rhagal will be able to defeat the undead dragonwight.  I can't picture anyone else getting close to it's deadly blue "unfire"

Comment: @m1gp0z Thanks for the comment reminded me to update the answer, Viserion is a "White Flyer" not a wight.

Comment: Cool! I didn't know this had been confirmed