# Can the Night King walk through wildfire?

Tags: game-of-thrones

White Walkers can be eliminated by using fire. However, there are some cases that happened (in the series), where the Night King either walked right through it or the radiance of their coldness are far superior than the dragon fire's strength. (I have no idea whether a dragon's fire is just a normal fire).

Wildfire has been used to defeat Stannis and his alliances when he invaded King's Landing. Wildfire caused explosions that burned Stannis' fleet. Wildfire even surpassed a normal fire since its strength cannot be diminished by the water.

With the level a Wildfire has, is the Night King still able to walk through it? As far as I know, Wildfire can cause worse damages than normal fire.

*Note: I haven't read the books yet.*

[image: Wildfire at the Battle of Blackwater]

Comment: Regarding your first sentence, I don't think normal fire can kill a White Walker. At the very least we haven't see it in the show. However, the question has value since wildfire is different than normal fire. Come to think of it, has fire ever even stalled a White Walker?

Comment: @svenvo7 We've seen the White Walkers interact with "normal" fire but not wildfire of dragonfire.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of the [FWP](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based). As of now there is not any encounter between WW and WF but there certainly will be in next season when WW go south and Humans throw everything they got at the Others.

Comment: Also for what it's worth "White Walkers can be eliminated by using fire." is incorrect. I think you mean wights can be killed by fire.

Comment: @Aegon Per [this clarification to the FWP](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11865/31394), a question like this isn't closeworthy: it's asking about the canon as a whole, and could reasonably be answered based on current canon. "*"No answer known yet but may be revealed in future works" is an excellent answer but NOT a valid reason to VTC.*"

Comment: @Randal'Thor I think you made the wrong choice on this as FWP is used for cases where the answer is not known yet but will most likely be revealed in the future.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Please check the meta post I linked. The policy explicitly says: "*"No answer known yet but may be revealed in future works" is an excellent answer but NOT a valid reason to VTC.*"

Comment: @Randal'Thor "This is a bit difficult to do with precision in all cases, as some questions may be borderline (in a sense of, it may ask about something technically about Episode 8, but to any canon expert, it's clear that the answer will be unknown till Episode 9 - personally I'd be OK with FWPing such a question but wouldn't be heartbroken if it stays open)." is the clear part to me. The answer is clearly going to be addressed in Season 8 so FWP. So according to policy you shouldn't really have overridden the communities votes on the review.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I don't think it falls into that category. Instead it falls into the category of *"VTC as future works, since Episode 9 is not released yet; and the question cannot be answered well from episode 8."* Replace Episode with Season. We can't answer it from the Seasons we have seen so far, even not from the books. There is not enough data even to speculate based on logic. Question like [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/134415/54887) can be answered by speculation based on available data as we have seen Dragons vs Wargs. But We have not seen WW vs WF.

Comment: @Aegon This question is **not** of the form *"In Episode 9, did Spoiler spoiler the Spoiler?"* - it's of the form *"In Star Wars, did Spoiler spoiler the Spoiler?"* (replace SW with GoT). No mention of future seasons here, just a general question. If we don't know the answer from the seasons so far, then it sounds like precisely a case of *"No answer known yet but may be revealed in future works"*.

Comment: There's less information in the books but I can provide some better quotes from there. Is book information acceptable?

Comment: I would close it because of its completely incorrect opening statement.

Comment: @TheMathemagician You shouldn't close something because of a false premise, potential mis wording or incorrect statement. That is something you correct in an answer or comment.

Comment: [Linked meta discussion](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12016/54887)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [We Do Not Know](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd0V5.jpg)

There are three types of fire in Game of Thrones and in order of least to most powerful they are:

- Fire
- Wildfire
- Dragon fire

From those three, we've only seen the White Walkers interact with one of the types of fire: fire. Here the fire parted around them to let them pass, how this happens is speculation but probably because "They bring the cold with them". See the below image from Season 6 Episode 5, "The Door".

[image: The Night King parts fire]

I believe a similar image is shown in Season 7 Episode 6, "Beyond the Wall", when the Night King and some White Walkers have fire around them.

On the other end of the spectrum we have dragon fire, this is speculated to be able to kill White Walkers but as of yet we have not seen that happen. It is speculated because of dragon glass, or obsidian, which has been known to kill them, see [my related answer here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/178443/58193).

Lastly, we have wildfire which I don't think has been seen to interact with White Walkers and even their wights. It is a mix between the two though probably closer to normal fire than dragon fire. I would speculate that it would not kill them but that is just speculation on my part and we are likely to know more in Season 8

> now that the White Walkers have broken through the Wall and man is going to throw everything they have at them.

---

On a side note the following statement of your is incorrect, we have only seen fire, and dragon fire for that matter, kill wights but not White Walkers.

> White Walkers can be eliminated by using fire.

Comment: Thank you for correcting *wights* and *White Walkers*.

Comment: @Invoker [Related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/12065/58193) though from the books perspective things are mainly similar here. (Others are White Walkers in case you didn't know)